# Filering the list of the links

Tags: android, jsoup

i'm using library called Jsoup. My goal is to fetch only list items from the list provided in this site :

```
[https://uzdarbis.lt/f109/it-darbo-pasiulymai/][1]
```

This is the code i wrote in Android:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://uzdarbis.lt/f109/it-darbo-pasiulymai/").get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

     for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element elem : links){
          Log.i(TAG, i +"   "+elem.attr("abs:href"));
     }
```

Here is my problem, i get all links of the page. How may i filter it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your selector will select every `a` element with an `href` attribute.  If you want to select only some of the links, you need to make your selector more specific.

You didn't specify exactly which links you want, so I'm going to assume you want to select the topic title links.  To do this, you need to find some other property of the `a` elements you can add to your selector -- usually an attribute, but also possibly a relation to other page elements (such as "always a child of a `td` element).  In this case it's simple: topic title links all have class `topic_title`, so you'd change your selector to

```
Elements links = doc.select("a.topic_title[href]");
```

Suppose instead you wanted to select all links in the table of topics (topic titles and other links too).  Here you'd want to select only `a` elements that are (direct or indirect) children of the `table` with id `forum_table`:

```
Elements links = doc.select("table#forum_table a[href]");
```

If you wanted something else, you should use your browser's "inspect element" feature to look at the elements you want and their parents to find properties you can use in your selector.  You can look at the [selector documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) to see what properties you can use.